# Question on multivariable limit

Tags: limits

Does the following limit:

$$\lim_{(x\rightarrow\infty,y\rightarrow-\infty)}\frac{x^2}{-y}$$

exist? And if so, what is it? Apologies for asking such a basic question!

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. We don't mind basic questions, as long as you show what you have tried and where you are stuck. If you edit the question to provide that you are more likely to get answers rather than downvotes and votes to close.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim(x-%3Einfinity,+y-%3E-infinity)+x%5E2%2F-y  Your limit would evaluate to $\frac{\infty^2}{\infty}$ which is undefined.

Comment: It doesn't exist. You can clearly see the path dependence leaving the origin by setting, say $y = mx$ and going out to infinity.

Comment: If you cannot evaluate a limit, you may wish to prove that the limit doesn't exist. For a multivariable limit, you can try and see if the limit changes based on the path on which you go, and as mentioned by AlfredYerger in the comment above, this particular limit _is_ path dependent, and so doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks Alfred, that's what I'd tried. It just seemed too simple, somehow. Thanks again.

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Comment: @Stadius http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Consider taking the limit along the paths ($x \to \infty$):

- $y=-x$
- $y=-x^2$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**
Let's first assume they approach at the same speed, i.e. that $x = -y$. Then,
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty, y \to -\infty} \frac{x^2}{-y}
 = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2}{x} = +\infty.
$$

What happens when $x^2 = -y$? What can you conclude about the existence of this limit?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider

$$\lim_{x^2+y^2\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x^2}{-y} \quad y<0$$

which clearly does not exist.

Indeed $$x=0 \implies\frac{x^2}{-y}=0 \quad $$

and $$|x|=y \implies\frac{x^2}{-y}=x\to\pm\infty \quad $$